Properties of field extensions of finite transcendence degree
Let $K/F$ be a field extension of transcendence degree $n\ge 2$. If $E$ is a subfield of $K$ such that $F\subset E \subset K$ and the transcendence degree of $E$ over $F$ equals $n-1$,
then $K$ is a function field of some curve defined over $E$.
Is it possible to choose the field $E$ so that the corresponding curve has an $E$-rational point?
In other words, does there exist a subfield $E$ such that $K$ is the function field of a curve over $E$ with a rational point?
I think  similar questions have been considered in algebraic geometry, but I cannot find the answer.
Maybe someone can help with a proof or a counterexample?
